# Problem in RS485 Communication between Arduino and PC

Tags: rs485, rs232

I'm trying to sending and receiving data via RS485 communication. Interfacing Arduino and PC(laptop) 
using SN75176 RS485. I wrote a program to send a string "Hello" from arduino via Tx pin. My intention is to receive
the "Hello" string in my PC's hyperterminal. After uploading the program im receiving junk data. The baud rate i've mentioned in
my program and i gave in hyperterminal are same. I've checked the wire connection, it is ok. Then, what is the problem?

Code:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int Txpin = 1;
int ditpin = 5;  //for 1st rs485
int ditpin1 = 2; //for 2nd rs485
void setup()
  {
          // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Txpin,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ditpin, HIGH); //For transmit data from arduino
    digitalWrite(ditpin1, LOW); //For receive data to hyperterminal
  }

void loop() 
  {
    Serial.println("Hello\r\n");
    delay(1000);
  }
```

Wire connection:

[image]

Comment: No ground on the PC side?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...No. I didnt connect. Will it be the problem?

Comment: Instead i short both rs485 GND.

Comment: The control pin, VCC and ground is not correctly wired on the PC side. Google how to connect RS485. Too many issues with this wiring. Please see this reference. http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428

Comment: Hi @MikaelPatel. Thanks for the post. Actually i'm not connecting two arduinos, connecting one arduino to PC using RS232 converter. As you said i connected the rs232 converter's(5th pin) GND to RS485's GND, but i'm giving power supply 5v it from arduino board on PC side since my rs232 converter doesnt have power supply pins.

Comment: Please start by fixing the ground connection to the PC. There are other issues but start with that.

Comment: Hi @MikaelPatel. I did that ground connection correctly. Still can't receive the data.

Comment: Did you forget the 120 ohm resistors?

Comment: Is 120 ohm will be the problem? I read that "to use resistor for long distance". Is it should place? Thanks..

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. You do know that the signal (R) is not RS232 levels? It is 5V. I think you are looking for a TTL to RS232 converter and not RS485. Something like http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf. Or http://www.ebay.com/itm/MAX3232-RS232-Serial-Port-To-TTL-Converter-Module-Male-DB9-COM-Serial-MAX232/221545502349?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D34875%26meid%3D8f4caa5def98499c9502dd70b3505a35%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D221022603873

Comment: Hi @MikaelPatel. what about using 5v to 3.3v voltage divider circuit? Will it work [link](http://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J1423.600.png?ba900a2037e04a07928013504b82c1f6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect from Arduino serial input/output with RS485 circuit and then to the PC RS232 port. You need a TTL to RS232 adapter. For instance an adapter based on [MAX3222](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf).

[image: MAX3232 circuit diagram]

Cheers!